# Airflow on demand DAG with multiple instances running at the sametime

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to see if I airflow is a good fit for this scenario. At present, I have a DAG. This looks for a trigger file at s3, creates EMR cluster and submit spark job, then delete the EMR cluster. 
My requirement is to convert this into on demand run. There will be many users running the export from the application. For each export run, I will have to call this DAG. That means there will be more than once instance of the same DAG will be running at the sametime.

I know we an make an API call to trigger a DAG. But I am not sure if we can run more than once instance of a DAG at the sametime. Can anyone had similar use case?

Answer (score 2):

I am handling this with max_active_runs

```
dag = DAG(
    'dev_clickstream_v1',
    max_active_runs=5,
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=2),
    params=PARAMS
)
```

Comment: Hello! I was wondering if you found the answer? I'm in a similar scenario and need a way to run DAGs asynchronously and on-demand. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am making an API call to trigger the DAG. More importantly, need to set the max_active_runs parameter in the dag as mentioned above.